# VB.NET Multiple Table search function with Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

This code below is were my main seach function is. The problem is that i can't add more tables to make it search. It is only working with one table.

SQL= "SELECT * from **mydatabase** where **id** like '%" & search.Text & "%'"

What i want is something like this:
SQL= "SELECT * from **mydatabase** where **id, name, lastname** like '%" & search.Text & "%'"

I have tried diffrent types of code to make it happend, but there was no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You coure use OR condicions:

```
SQL= "SELECT * from mydatabase 
       where id like '%" & search.Text &"%"
          Or name like '%" & search.Text &"%"
          Or lastname like '%" & search.Text & "%'"
```

Comment: Won't work across tables. That was the actual question: multiple columns, multiple tables.

Comment: Please, what would be the expected results?

Comment: The question is unclear, but I guess you could use JOIN and OR to achieve your results.

Comment: It didn't work, but i am trying to use a combination: Dim tabel as strig = "id" & "name" & "lastname" And now i am trying this SQL= "SELECT * from mydatabase where tabel like '%" & search.Text & "%'". But i cant get that table betwen the "".

Comment: You can't. You must use the condition for EVERY field and use OR between them....